# Add elements to List<Map.Entry<Integer,Integer>>

Tags: java, list, dictionary, arraylist

```
List<Map.Entry<Integer,Integer>> openTimes = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<Integer,Integer>>();

for (int i=0; i<_elem.size(); i++)
{
  openTimes.add(i,_elem.get(i));
}
```

How to properly add elements to the list `openTimes`?

Comment: openTimes.add(new Entry(???))

Comment: What do you want to do? Why do you want to store the list index of an entry in the entry itself? That's completely useless!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is wrong  you declared your List as `List<Map.Entry<Integer,Integer>>` so therefore when you execute this line of code `openTimes.add(i,_elem.get(i));` what you are inserting not a Map. I think you are looking for something similar to this. What you can do is

I have no idea what do you want to do here but you can use this

```
//We get the first Map
Map<Integer,Integer> yourMap = _elem.get(0);

for (int i=0; i<_elem.size(); i++)
{
  yourMap.put(i,_elem.get(i))
}
```

or you can also use what  dasblinkenlight suggested.

Comment: That's only my rough assumption. The user did not clarify about the things he want to do. but for your sake let me update it.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i=0; i<_elem.size(); i++)
{
   Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> entry =
                    new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Integer, Integer>(i,_elem.get(i));
  openTimes.add(entry);
}
```

iterate over List

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> entry : openTimes)
{
     System.out.println(entry.getKey());
     System.out.println(entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you *must* have map entries there you need a `Map` from which to harvest these entries. One way to do this is as follows:

```
Map<Integer,Integer> tmp = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
for (int i=0; i<_elem.size(); i++) {
    tmp.put(i, _elem.get(i));
}
List<Map.Entry<Integer,Integer>> openTimes =
    new ArrayList<Map.Entry<Integer,Integer>>(tmp.entrySet());
```

You could also use [`AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<K,V>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.html) directly, or provide your own anonymous implementation.

A better solution would be defining your own class to represent key-value pairs.